# Trying to post data from Google Spreadsheet to a external Api

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm using Google SpreadSheet and IFTTT to do a DB Call Log of my phone, this is working perfect. 
Now I'm trying to populate a form in a web page by API from this DB Call Log.
I would like to send lastRow to my API every time IFTTT populate the Sheet.
The first Row in the Sheet is populated with headers name: departament, first_name, last_name, email, phone, deadline.

So i manage to send data to API like this:

```
function myFunction() {

var data = {

    'department':     1,
    'first_name' :    'Test',
    'last_name' :     'test',
    'email' :         'email@gmail.com',
    'phone' :         ["0700000000"],
    'deadline' :      '2017-04-10T00:00'
}

var payload = JSON.stringify(data)  

var headers = {

     'AUTHORIZATION': 'Token b8473654v6345teryrby456yrtyrtyertytdvfh87afc',
     // Add any other required parameters for XXX API.
};
var url = 'http://api.XXX.com/api/1.0/clients/';
var options = {
    'method': 'post',
    'contentType': 'application/json', 
    'headers': headers,
    'payload' : payload,
};
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
}
```

Now i need to automate it but i don't know how:

1. (this is a SpreadSheet question) IFTTT populate the "deadline" column in this format "April 10, 2017 at 01:54PM" however the needed format for API is "2017-04-10T13:54", how to auto modify it?
2. to get the values from Sheet cells (from lastRow) and send them throw json payload
3. to set a trigger event so the script trigger's every time IFTTT populates a new Row in the Sheet.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Will try to answer the question one by one:

1) Reformat date: You can use [Utilities.formatDate()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatDate(Date,String,String)) in apps script to modify your date.

Code:

```
function reformatDate(dtStr)
{
 if (dtStr == undefined)
 dtStr = "April 1, 2017 at 01:54PM"

 dtStr = dtStr.replace("at", "") // Remove at
 dtStr = dtStr.replace(/(\d)(PM)/g,"$1 $2") //Add a space between the time and PM
 dtStr = dtStr.replace(/(\d)(AM)/g,"$1 $2") //Add a space between the time and AM
 Logger.log(dtStr)

 dtStr = new Date(dtStr)
 var newDt = Utilities.formatDate(dtStr, SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm") 
 Logger.log(newDt)

 return newDt
}
```

2) Get last row Values: You can use `getLastRow()` and `getValues()` functions in apps scripts

```
function lastRowData(){
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
 var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet()
 var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow() 
 var lastCol = sheet.getLastColumn()
 var lastRowData = sheet.getRange(lastRow,1,1,lastCol).getValues()
 return lastRowData[0]

}
```

**Edit**

To get values as is i.e. displayed values in the sheet, you can modify the getvalues to getDisplayValues() like so:

```
var lastRowData = sheet.getRange(lastRow,1,1,lastCol).getDisplayValues()
```

3) Trigger your sheet: I will not reinvent the wheel here. But will provide you with an awesome answer from @Mogsdad
 Link: [Trigger an email when a cell is written into from another app (IFTTT)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26553713/trigger-an-email-when-a-cell-is-written-into-from-another-app-ifttt)

In short, you will have to use onEdit Trigger to detect new entries.
If on edit doesn't work, try on Change trigger.

Complete code:

```
function myFunction() {
var lastRow = lastRowData()
var data = {

    'department':     lastRow[0],
    'first_name' :    lastRow[1],
    'last_name' :     lastRow[2],
    'email' :         lastRow[3]',
    'phone' :         [lastRow[4]],
    'deadline' :      reformatDate(lastRow[5])
}

var payload = JSON.stringify(data)  

var headers = {

     'AUTHORIZATION': 'Token b8473654v6345teryrby456yrtyrtyertytdvfh87afc',
     // Add any other required parameters for XXX API.
};
var url = 'http://api.XXX.com/api/1.0/clients/';
var options = {
    'method': 'post',
    'contentType': 'application/json', 
    'headers': headers,
    'payload' : payload,
};
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Department no is 1.0 i needed 1 (no decimals). Phone no is not correct i need a 10 digits no, my current no is 727656656 and i need 0727656656.                                 
   [code]function createSpreadsheetEditTrigger() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('PipeLine')
      .forSpreadsheet(ss)
      .onEdit()
      .create();
} [code]     This is the piece of code for Trigger but is not working as expected( it triggers when I modify a cell in the sheet. but it's not working when a new Row is auto inserted by IFTTT.

Comment: I have edited the above answer to show the display value as is!

Comment: As for the trigger, could you try onChange event instead and see if that gets triggered by an update from IFTTT.

Comment: It's working with onChange. Here is the code for the trigger [code]function onChange(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('PipeLine')
      .forSpreadsheet(ss)
      .onChange()
      .create();
}[code] But getDisplayValues() is not doing anything. maybe because the text come in this format from IFTTT, The phone no. it's without 0 so i have to use a ".replace" command to modify it. I tried with custom number format, it's visually working (i can see the change in sheet) but the script doesn't get the right format. Thank you again!!!

Comment: Jack Brown . I notice a problem with function dataReformat. The time is wrong, exactly the minutes. For example "April 1, 2017 at 01:54PM" it's reformated in "2017-04-01T13:05". It cuts the last no. from minute format (in this example "4"). The problem is persistent with any combination of numbers or PM/AM format. Tx.

Comment: Run the reformatedate function by itself and look at the logs. Let me know what's the output.

Comment: That is exactly what i did. I think the problem lies in dtStr = dtStr.replace(/\d(PM)/g, " PM") and dtStr = dtStr.replace(/\d(AM)/, " AM")

Comment: Thank you very much!!! I have another question but it's regarding next step in my little call log. So i'l post a new question. Tx again for all your help.